# ERROR: not found COREDLL.dll

Tags: windows-xp, vcredist

I'm trying to run a program, but this occurs the following error:

> Error: This application can not be started because it was not found COREDLL.dll

This error occurs in the WinXP and Win7

I downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) but this error continue.

What can it be? How can I solve?

Thanks,

Comment: what kind of program ? did you write it ?

Comment: COREDLL.DLL is the compact .NET framework for mobile devices. Are you sure the program you're running is compatible with Windows XP?

Comment: So, I was reading about this "dll" and I saw that is for mobile systems.
I did two tests on a computer with WinXP test (Ok) and on another computer Win7 and WinXP, occurs this error.

I need to run some software models in Portico, was using version 1.0.2, now I'm testing the new version 2.0.

The Portico support said that the problem was related to the lack of Microsoft Visual Studio redistributable, but I installed.